# Error while creating an Endpoint in Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, endpoint, inference

I am trying to use PytorchModel to deploy a trained model outside Sagemaker to an endpoint. This is my code

```
pytorch_model = PyTorchModel(model_data='model.tar.gz', role=role,source_dir='model/code',entry_point='inference.py',framework_version='1.3.1',py_version='py3')
pytorch_model.deploy(instance_type='ml.t2.medium', initial_instance_count=1,endpoint_name='test',overwrite=True)
```

I keep getting the below error and not able to understand why

```
ERROR - %s already exists.
Please specify --force/-f option to overwrite the model archive output file.
```

Comment: Are you providing an S3 URI for the `model_data` parameter? SageMaker does not currently support local tarballs when creating an endpoint.

Comment: Yes I do.. I just haven't mentioned it here.